# Magento 2: Very long loading JavaScript on website

Tags: magento2

Our site has recently started to load  a very long time. Does anyone know what this may be due to? I think is any issue with JS.

Does anyone know what this may be due to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the image 
https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/pub/media/wysiwyg/logo.png

to

http://claue.magesolution.com/pub/media/logo/default/logo.png

and you should be seeing this resolved.

Looks like your site uses a CDN that slows down everything in your site?

Comment: @ Herve, I think you have right.  This link no work: http://claue.magesolution.com/pub/media/logo/default/logo.png but how I can delete this link from my website? Where is located ? Because this link leads to the creator of the template, and this logo does not work only, I can not locate it anywhere it is.

Comment: likely in the core_config_data table: select * from core_config_data where value like '%claue%'; should help